# Process Builder : Obtaining Id value from text field

Tags: workflow, process-builder

We have the following requirement to assign leads to a campaign as soon as they are created.

I am trying to utilize Lightining Process Builder for this requirement.

I am stuck at the place where I need to insert a new Campaign Member (the association of lead to campaign).

As shown in the picture for Campaign Id value I am inputting the below ( `[Lead].Campaign_Salesforce_id__c` )

It is erroring saying that ID values should contain only 15 or 18 digit Ids.

[image]

All of our incoming leads will have a text field (Campaign_Lead_Id__c) which will continue the 18 digit salesforce id of the campaign.

Can someone tell me how am I supposed to set this field's value as Campaign Id value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For now that is still a limitation with declarative workflow or process builder. An ID field can either be hardcoded or matched against another ID field to accept its value. A trigger/Apex class can get around this but obviously you need code in order to make that work.**

Answer (score -1):

I guess, you need to use Type as 'Reference' instead of Id since you are inserting Campaign Member which has a field value referenced to Lead object.

Comment: If you choose reference you will be able to choose only "Id" fields and not text fields even though they may contain Id data

Answer (score -1):

You can create a formula field to capture the ID and then use that formula field in the Process Builder.

Thanks,
Vipul

Comment: Nope..it wont work